# Power Automate Query suddenly started throwing error on filter query

Tags: power-automate

I have a Power Automate which was working fine until a few weeks ago and it started throwing this error:

`The expression "field_1 eq East-Rm 145-A FD (In" is not valid. Creating query failed. clientRequestId: 1a032384-8dac-45bb-861d-d605d11e1ef3 serviceRequestId: 33bc12a1-50d7-0000-1bf2-23ce0201e529`

[image]

This is the setup where the error is happening.

[image]This was working fine until recently. Any ideas would be appreciated because I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just figured it out. I had to add a single quote around the dynamic content

[image]

It's working again. I don't know why it worked fine before, but I'm glad I figured it out and hopefully my question will help someone else.